# Ajax request to self-page not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php page with the follow javascript code in it:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function() {
                HLalert('Saving...');
                $.getJSON("<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>", {
                    ajax: 1,
                    classes: $("#alllessons").serialize()
                }, function(output) {
                    if (output.status == false) { HLalert(output.message); }
                    else { HLalert('Saved!.'); }
                });
            });
```

For whatever real it does not work.  The javascript before and after it exectute but these seemingly does not.  Not even a failed status is returned.

HLalert() is a function that displays a twitter like alert message.

At the top of the php page I have the code

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
        // parse the ajax values
        // output json and die
    }
    // regular page code
```

I tried changing the names of the passed values in the getJSON call, that doesn't do anything.  I've tried putting the page the getJSON calls into a different file and that doesn't do anything either.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my getJSON code that I just cannot see?  Are you allowed to make $.ajax calls to your self-page?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Did you look at the source of your page in a browser to see if the generated JavaScript looked sane? Did you look at Firebug or your browser's developer tools to see if an HTTP request was made, and if so, whether there was JSON in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ? I am not really sure if there is a `$PHP_SELF`.

Comment: No it works. I checked the source and the url in the javascript is outputting to the proper page.

Comment: @Josh Weissbock try looking into firebug->Net->XHR and see if your params (ajax, classes) are being passed as intended. You might also want to add a 2nd argument(status) into your callback to check if it is a "success" `function output(data, status)`.

Answer (score 1):

`$PHP_SELF` does not exist unless you have defined it.

Do you perhaps mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

**Edit:** `.serialize()` returns a string without quotes and I think the values of your key - value pairs do need to be quoted so perhaps it should be something like:

after the first alert:

```
var values = '"' + $("#alllessons").serialize() + '"';
```

and later:

```
ajax: 1,
classes: values
```

Comment: No it works. I checked the source and the url in the javascript is outputting to the proper page.

Comment: I have on another page $.getJSON("/backend/links-save.php" { orderInfo: $("#formItems").serialize(), page: '<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>' }, function(output) { if (output.status == false) { HLalert(output.message); } else { HLalert("Saved Successfully."); } });  And that works.  I will still try this method just in case.

Comment: @Josh Weissbock What happens if you replace that with just `classes: "test"`?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean document.location ? ;-)
No need for PHP here.